# How write a PL/SQL program that prints out string which looking like xml format

Tags: oracle, plsql

Input String : “a4b4c2d9d9c2e6e6b4s2o1o1s2a4w2r8r8k3g5g5k3w2”
I tried this code as first step:

```
declare
   word varchar2(50)  := 'a4b4c2d9d9c2e6e6b4s2o1o1s2a4w2r8r8k2g5g5k2w2';
   num  number        := length(word)/2;
   name_array dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
begin
   dbms_output.put_line(word);
   FOR i IN 1..num LOOP
      name_array(i) := substr(word, -2*i, 2);
   END LOOP;
   FOR i IN name_array.FIRST .. name_array.LAST LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line(name_array(i));
   END LOOP;
end;
```

This code creates only an array of string. Not xml format. I need this output:

[image: ı need this output:]

Which SQL functions,conditional clauses... do I need to use?

Comment: I see no XML markup in the desired output.

Comment: Which are the tags ? what are the values? Is it being picked from any table?

Comment: @Serg ı just need a output looking like xml format.this is about 
the alignment of the letters and the determination of the necessary spaces.

Comment: @Dawn   ıt isnt picking from any table ı just have input string value.these are all information for me to find a solution.
I am aware that it is not enough

Comment: Most probably it's a stack programming exersize. You need a collection of open nodes which is  EXTENDed / TRIMed  as you parse next item. see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005

Comment: @ecenurozturk It looks like you're walking the string backwards from the end two characters at a time as if each two character sequence is supposed to be considered the name of an XML element. When you re-encounter an element, it indicates the end of that element. As long as an element cannot be recursive within itself and the data are guaranteed to adhere to the rules, then, yes, I agree it is a push-pop type of exercise. If either of those two constraints don't hold, then you have a lot more coding.

Comment: What do you mean by "like xml format"? You can write entry xml document in a single line.

Comment: Your sample output looks nothing like XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CHARS_TABLE IS TABLE OF CHAR(2);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE INTEGERS_TABLE IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/
```

**PL/SQL**:

This assumes a well-formed set of character pairs and just indents each pair to the appropriate level:

```
DECLARE
  word VARCHAR2(50) := 'a4b4c2d9d9c2e6e6b4s2o1o1s2a4w2r8r8k2g5g5k2w2';
  num  PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH( word ) / 2;
  name_array  CHARS_TABLE    := CHARS_TABLE();
  depth_array INTEGERS_TABLE := INTEGERS_TABLE();
  open_array  INTEGERS_TABLE := INTEGERS_TABLE();
BEGIN
  name_array.EXTEND( num );
  depth_array.EXTEND( num );
  open_array.EXTEND( num );

  name_array(1)  := SUBSTR( word, 1, 2 );
  depth_array(1) := 1;
  open_array(1)  := 1;

  FOR i IN 2 .. num LOOP
    name_array(i) := SUBSTR( word, 2*i - 1, 2 );
    open_array(i) := 1;
    FOR j IN 1 .. i-1 LOOP
      IF name_array(j) = name_array(i) THEN
        open_array(i) := -open_array(i);
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    depth_array(i) := depth_array(i-1) + open_array(i);
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. num LOOP
    FOR j IN 2 .. depth_array(i) + CASE open_array(i) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( '  ' );
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( name_array(i) );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Output**:

```
a4
  b4
    c2
      d9
      d9
    c2
    e6
    e6
  b4
  s2
    o1
    o1
  s2
a4
w2
  r8
  r8
  k2
    g5
    g5
  k2
w2
```

**Update - Simpler Stack-Based Version**:

```
DECLARE
  word        CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'a4b4c2d9d9c2e6e6b4s2o1o1s2a4w2r8r8k2g5g5k2w2';
  num         CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH( word ) / 2;
  name_array  CHARS_TABLE := CHARS_TABLE();
  depth       PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  name        CHAR(2);

  PROCEDURE indent( depth PLS_INTEGER, name CHAR )
  IS
  BEGIN
    FOR j IN 2 .. depth LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( '  ' );
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( name );
  END;
BEGIN
  name_array.EXTEND( num );

  FOR i IN 1 .. num LOOP
    name := SUBSTR( word, 2*i - 1, 2 );
    IF depth > 0 AND name = name_array(depth) THEN
      indent(depth,name);
      depth := depth - 1;
    ELSE
      depth := depth - 1;
      name_array(depth) := name;
      indent(depth,name);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you very much :) I need a little more  help .How can I reverse the output ?I mean  your output starts with a4 b4 c2 d9.... but my output w2 k3 g5...  @MT0

Comment: @ecenurozturk Look at the difference between `SUBSTR()` calls in your question and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
  vs_CurrentChar VARCHAR2(1);
  vs_NextChar    VARCHAR2(1);
  vs_TempText    VARCHAR2(100);
  vs_InputText   VARCHAR2(100) := 'abcdffdcba';

  vn_LengthOfText NUMBER := 1;
  vn_WhileIndex   NUMBER := 1;

  vs_Spaces VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
  vs_TempText    := NULL;
  vs_CurrentChar := substr(vs_InputText, vn_WhileIndex, vn_LengthOfText);
  dbms_output.put_line(vs_CurrentChar);

  WHILE vn_WhileIndex < length(vs_InputText) - 1 LOOP

    vs_NextChar := substr(vs_InputText, vn_WhileIndex + 1, vn_LengthOfText);
    EXIT WHEN vs_CurrentChar = vs_NextChar;

    vs_TempText    := vs_TempText || vs_CurrentChar;
    vs_CurrentChar := vs_NextChar;
    vs_Spaces      := NULL;
    FOR i IN 1 .. vn_WhileIndex LOOP
      vs_Spaces := vs_Spaces || chr(9); --'*';
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line(vs_Spaces || vs_CurrentChar);
    vn_WhileIndex := vn_WhileIndex + 1;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line(vs_Spaces || vs_CurrentChar);

  FOR i IN 1 .. length(vs_TempText) LOOP
    vs_Spaces      := substr(vs_Spaces, vn_LengthOfText, length(vs_Spaces) - 1);
    vs_CurrentChar := substr(vs_TempText, -i, vn_LengthOfText);
    dbms_output.put_line(vs_Spaces || vs_CurrentChar);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**And output:**

```
a
    b
        c
            d
                f
                f
            d
        c
    b
a
```

even, if you put **'*';** instead of **chr(9);** then output will look like as:

```
a
*b
**c
***d
****f
****f
***d
**c
*b
a
```